# Parse class objects no longer working in Xcode 8.3

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I recently updated my Xcode to Xcode 8.3.2 and ran the swift syntax updater. As a result of this update my Parse classes no longer work and I am not sure how fix them.

The error I am receiving is 'Static member 'registerSubclass' cannot be used on instance of type 'County'

The class looks like this.

```
import Foundation

class County : PFObject, PFSubclassing {

private lazy var __once: () = {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }()

@NSManaged var Name: String

override class func initialize() {
    var onceToken : Int = 0;
    _ = self.__once

}

class func parseClassName() -> String{
    return "County"
 }
}
```

I am also not understanding why in this update I am getting errors on when  using self to call class level methods from within an enclosure?

Comment: Try: `County.registerSubclass()` instead of `self.registerSubclass()`

Comment: That seems to work for registerSubClass however using the class name instead of self on .__once results in the following. Instance member '__once' cannot be used on type 'County'. Do you know why self. no longer works in this version of swift?

Comment: `__once` is not static.

Comment: How do I reference __once in Swift 3? self.__once worked in the previous version.

Comment: You can not call an instance variable from a class (static) method. Make `__once` static.